# Can we place the addon in textInputAddon to right side in R shiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I tried to have an icon in text input in R shiny. I used textInputAddon to add the icon but it is placed on the left side by default.

```
textInputAddon("tia1",label = NULL,value = "99", addon = icon("percent"))
```

Is there any way to place it on the right side?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do would be using HTML as shown below:

```
 library(shiny)
  library(shinyWidgets)

  ui <- fluidPage(

    # textInputAddon("tia1",label = NULL,value = "99", addon = icon("percent"))
    tags$head(HTML('<link href="shared/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">')),
    HTML('<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;" class="input-group">
         <input id="tia1" type="text" class="form-control shiny-bound-input" value="99">
         <span class="input-group-addon">
         <i class="fa fa-percent">

         </i>
         </span>
         </div>
         </div>')
  )

  server <- function(input, output){}


  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Using this code you get `textInputAddon` as follows:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you also help me in naming the id dynamically?

Comment: You can use `uiOutput` and `renderUI` in  use the HTML code in `renderUI` and give the ID dynamically.